# Hangman game queries

Tags: python

I have got the code from the net and made some modifications.

1. I want the name of the country to be asked for every once. Whenever I run the code, the name of the same country sometimes gets asked after every few turns. Can I limit the same to only 1 time??
2. Also, I am getting the error sometimes that even if the name of the country is entered correctly, I am showed that "You Lost".

For the first, I have tried using random shuffle, however, I am getting an error.

```
import random
from collections import Counter

fruits =  """algeria spain armenia barbados chile ecuador ghana jamaica luxemborg kuwait monaco
senegal turkey"""
fruit1 = random.choice(fruits.split(" "))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hangman Game: Guess the name of the Country \n You have {} chances".format(len(fruit1)+3))

    for i in fruit1:
        print("_" , end=" ")
    print()

    #playing = True
    chances = len(fruit1) + 3
    Guess = ""
    count = 0

    try:
            while (chances != 0):
                print()
                chances -= 1

                try:
                     guess = str(input("Enter a letter:  "))
                except:
                      print("Enter only a letter")
                      continue

                if not guess.isalpha():
                        print("Enter only an alphabet")
                        chances +=1
                        continue
                elif len(guess)>1:
                        print("Enter only a single alphabet")
                        chances +=1
                        continue
                elif guess in Guess:
                        print("Letter already guessed")
                        chances += 1
                        continue

                if guess in fruit1:
                    Guess += guess

                for q in fruit1:
                    if q in Guess:
                        print(q,end = " ")
                        count +=1
                    else:
                        print("_",end=" ")

                if (Counter(Guess) == Counter(fruit1)):
                    print()
                    print("Congratulations")
                    break

            if chances == 0:
                print()
                print("You lost")
                print("The word was: {}".format(fruit1))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()
        print("Bye")
        exit()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: For (1), `random.shuffle` the words, then iterate the shuffled words.

Comment: your 2nd error is because of this `if chances == 0:`. Sometime the user might be guessing at the last chance, so the counter become zero although the guessed word was right. So, you get both the statements, Congats and you lost

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can I limit the same [name] to only 1 time?

You cannot easily across different invocations. Each time a program is started, it begins in a clean state with no knowledge of what could have happened in previous runs. So you will have to either save the used words in a file and read that file (if it exists) at the beginning of the program or have the program loop and propose a new name.
In either case you should remove the used names from the `fruits` list.

> 2. sometimes ... even if the name of country is entered correctly, I am showed that "You Lost".

You are comparing counters. It is fine if a name as no repeated letter, because in that case the count of each letter is one. But for `armenia`, `Counter(fruit)` will contain `'a': 2`, while `Counter(Guess)` will have `'a': 1`. You should instead compare with `set`:

```
if (set(Guess) == set(fruit1)):
```